# Structing my Selenium Test

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a Selenium test case that I need to write, but before it executes I need to get some information from the user for the Test to run.

Currently, my code is structured like this:

```
public class myTest {
private WebDriver driver;

    @Before
     System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
"C:\\Users\\ktuck\\Documents\\Selenium\\Selenium Server\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); // I guess I don't need to fire this up as i'm only collecting information from the user?

    @Test

    // Code to collect user inputted data to use later in my test

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit(); // Do I need this?
    }

}
```

My initial thoughts were to put the collection code inside of a `main` function and then call the rest of my test script which would be in a different file, passing the information collected into it. But I'm not quite sure how to do that as I'm quite new to Selenium/Java :p

Can anyone help?

Comment: do you use any testing framework ?

Comment: We use Maven. Is there one you recommend?

Comment: maven is build+dependency tool. do you use jUnit or TestNG ?

Comment: Ah, in that case.. no. Are there any advantages over using one or the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using any testing framework , you can choose TestNG. TestNG supports Data driven and parameterized test.

you can pass param  via testng.xml. 
since you are using maven you can configure maven to pass parameters without using testng.xml.

you can also pass params to TestNG via maven through command line like below

```
mvn -Dtest=<testName> -D<paramName>=<paramValue>  test
```

if you dont want to use any of the testing framework then you can pass the param via JVM arg
and retrive it using  `System.getProperty("paramName")`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a test framework like JUnit or TestNG. This would enable you to use methods that are run before and after the actual test (as indicated by the pseudo-code given above).

Using this approach, you can do all the lookup stuff in the @BeforeClass method and quit the webdriver in the @AfterTest method. To keep the test class clean, I recommend to move the @BeforeClass and @AfterTest to an abstract super class which you inherit from.

**Abstract Superclass**

```
public abstract class AbstractSeleniumTest {

    private WebDriver webDriver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
       // do all the initalization stuff, e.g. system property lookup
    }

    @AfterTest(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDown() {
       // do all the clean-up stuff, e.g. webdriver.quit();
    }
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@Test
public class MySeleniumTest extends AbstractSeleniumTest {

     public void testSomething() {
           // do the actual test logic
     }

}
```

I hope this covers most of your question. For further assistance, please give more information.